# Non-blocking server using Java NIO

Tags: java, tcp, nio

I'm using [this](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) tutorial to build a java nio server without the writable section.

All works fine, except for one interesting thing:

- When the client is sending packets too fast, the server does not receives all messages, the server is always getting the first and the second packets but not more than that.
- If the client is sending the packets slowly the server gets all the packets.

Any idea?

I'm adding the server class code , if you need another class that mentioned in the code below , i'm here :).

NIOServer class :

```
package server;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class NioServer implements Runnable {



// The host:port combination to listen on
  private InetAddress hostAddress;
  private int port;

  // The channel on which we'll accept connections
  private ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

  // The selector we'll be monitoring
  private Selector selector;

  //the cach will hundle the messages that came
  private Cache cache;

  // The buffer into which we'll read data when it's available
  private ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);

  public NioServer(InetAddress hostAddress, int port , Cache cache) throws IOException {
    this.cache = cache;
    this.hostAddress = hostAddress;
    this.port = port;
    this.selector = this.initSelector();
  }


  private Selector initSelector() throws IOException {
        // Create a new selector
        Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();

        // Create a new non-blocking server socket channel
        this.serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Bind the server socket to the specified address and port
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(this.hostAddress, this.port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(isa);

        // Register the server socket channel, indicating an interest in 
        // accepting new connections
        serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        return socketSelector;
      }

  private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        // For an accept to be pending the channel must be a server socket channel.
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

        // Accept the connection and make it non-blocking
        SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Register the new SocketChannel with our Selector, indicating
        // we'd like to be notified when there's data waiting to be read
        socketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
      }

  private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        // Clear out our read buffer so it's ready for new data
        this.readBuffer.clear();

        // Attempt to read off the channel
        int numRead;
        try {
          numRead = socketChannel.read(this.readBuffer);
          String test = new String(this.readBuffer.array());
          System.out.print(test);

        } catch (IOException e) {
          // The remote forcibly closed the connection, cancel
          // the selection key and close the channel.
        //  key.cancel();
        //  socketChannel.close();
          return;
        }

        if (numRead == -1) {
          // Remote entity shut the socket down cleanly. Do the
          // same from our end and cancel the channel.
          key.channel().close();
          key.cancel();
          return;
        }

        // Hand the data off to our worker thread
        this.cache.processData(this, socketChannel, this.readBuffer.array(), numRead); 
      }

  public void run() {
        while (true) {
          try {
            // Wait for an event one of the registered channels

            this.selector.select();



            // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
            Iterator selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
              SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
              selectedKeys.remove();

              if (!key.isValid()) {
                continue;
              }

              // Check what event is available and deal with it
              if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                this.accept(key);
              } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                this.read(key);
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    try {
        Cache cache = new Cache();
        new Thread(cache).start();
      new Thread(new NioServer(null, 9090,cache)).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: There must be a bug in your code. If you want more help, give us more information.

Comment: TCP doesn't lose data and neither does NIO. You are either not reading all the data or throwing some of it away. Without some code to comment on it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: 1. If you catch an IOException when reading, you must (a) log it and (b) close the channel. 2. You don't need to cancel the key after closing e channel.

Comment: NB 1. This is a non-blocking server, not an asynchronous server. 2. The ROX NIO Tutorial was discredited many years before this question was posted. I've written extensively on it in the Sun/Oracle Java forums. It contains numerous errors of fact and much poor programming.

Comment: This quesiton should be closed as the OP has provided no sending code and no evidence in eight years, and @BillTheLizard my correct answer to it should be restored.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne What tutorial would you suggest learning to build a Java server from?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that if you were reading UDP. Note how slowly you are processing your packets on the `read` method. You are printing them to system.out which is very slow plus not sure how fast you are able to handle the data to the other thread on the `processData` method. [This library](http://mentaqueue.soliveirajr.com) I wrote can help you to do inter-thread non-blocking communication if that's the source of your lagging. You should also check the size of your underlying read socket buffer. The bigger it is is the more room you have to be quick and catch up before packets will start to get dropped. For TCP, you probably get an IOException on the channel if the underlying socket buffer gets full. For UDP the packets are silently dropped.

To have access to the underlying read socket buffer size you can do:

```
final Socket socket = channel.socket();
System.out.println(socket.getReceiveBufferSize());
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(newSize);
```

Note: AFAIK, Linux might require some OS configuration in order for you to change the underlying buffer size. If the `setReceiveBufferSize` has no effect (read it again to see if it was changed), google about it. :)

Comment: This is a TCP server.