# Multithreaded server in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, client-server, nio

The server is essentially a queue of items, while the clients act as producers and/or consumers of such items.

The server must:

- Listen for put / take requests and process them accordingly - this typically won't take too long, it consists of:

  1. Parsing a short string;
  2. An `HashMap.get`;
  3. Acquiring a lock;
  4. A `PriorityQueue.poll` or `PriorityQueue.offer`;
- Notify every client of all item activity, as soon as possible, so that every client has a *real-time* view of what's going on.

The easiest way of setting this up, is by having a thread `accept`ing clients, and then creating two threads for each client:

- One that handles the `InputStream`, which blocks waiting for requests;
- And another to handle the `OutputStream`, which listens for events on the queue, and sends the information to the client.

Surely this isn't scalable, and it seems wasteful to have two threads for each client.

I also thought about using a single thread, which would

- Set a socket timeout for `read` of about 1 second;
- Proceed to send every new event to the client, if the `read` times out, or after processing the request;
- Loop these two actions.

However, polling for requests and events is also wasteful.

Another approach would use a thread pool, and put each of the two above actions in their respective `Runnable`. These runnables would then queue each other in the `Executor`.
This seems just as wasteful, if not more.

I've been reading [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305386/java-nio-socketchannel-read-with-multithread?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848742/asynchronous-server-using-java-nio), and I'm now curious about NIO, since non-blocking operations and an event-driven server seems to be the right approach.

**Is any of the above designs suitable for this task, or should I tackle it with NIO?**

In terms of numbers, this is more of an exercise than a real system, so it *doesn't have to* deal with thousands of clients, but, ideally, it *should* be able to perform and scale well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two threads per client is definitely not scalable.

If you have M cores on the server, you can't actually do better than having M threads running.  Anything higher exposes you to thrashing, and will reduce the number of executed operations per second.

A better design partitions the available cores into U updaters and L listeners, where 
U + L == M.

Each client is assigned (ideally with load balancing, but that's an embellishment) to an updater thread.    Each update event is multicast to all the updater threads, which each then update all their assigned clients.  A client at the end of an updater's list is updated later than one at the beginning, but there is no help for it: you only have so much hardware.

Similarly, each client is assigned to a listener thread, which handles more than one listener.  Client input is dumped into a FIFO queue, and processed by the listener thread as soon as it gets around to it.

Each thread can then stay active and in memory, while client data is moved through the system.  The design degrades gracefully, in that too many clients means all updates get slow as a linear function of the number of clients.  The designs you propose will degrade faster than that.

Modern (e.g., later than, say 2002) web servers bury this all deep in the implementation, so developers don't need to manage it.  But it's still a useful exercise.

Comment: That makes sense. One of the main reasons for wanting a thread per client was that, if the connection was slow, then only that thread / client would suffer for it. Having a group of updater threads that would broadcast the events to all clients would suffer from slow connections, but I guess there's no way around that.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to keep using the ThreadPool because you need to manage Runners!, I suggest you impl MOA structure in your business, as this client connect to the server and server waits for the client request(data), then server queue the job(if there is no thread available to process) and imediatly response an long value which points to the client process id at the server and close the socket.
now what if clients request has processed and is ready for action? so here there is two approach, the good one is that server signal the client(so client needs to listen about the server response[ServerSocket]) about the finished request. OR client checks the server in some regular intervals and checks the status of the process.

Comment: *"server signal the client"* - What you're suggesting here, is basically an inversion of roles, isn't it? Having the client listen for a server response. I doubt that the requests would take long to process for this to be viable. Isn't the three-way handshake every now and then more costly than keeping the socket open?

Comment: keeping a connection open is worse than listening on a port. yes of course. as server is listening on port x for client requests, client listens on port y for responses. as I said, it's just a suggestion. but remember if client goes to open a port to get the response, so client should be reachable for server.

Answer (score 1):

The above design is completely fine. This is exactly how web-servers works before nio was introduced.

How many clients do you have ? If not so many, don't worry about scalability and try to avoid complicated nio api. If you really need to scale, consider using some kind of abstraction, netty for example. Using nio could be rather complicated and may not work same fashion on different OS (once I faced with weird bug, which can be reproduced only on specific OS).

With nio you can process all your clients request/response flow in 1-4 threads

Sometime IO could outperform NIO.

See this answer - [Old I/O thread per client model or NIO reactor pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113902/old-i-o-thread-per-client-model-or-nio-reactor-pattern)

Comment: Both the linked answer and its linked article were very insightful. *"The above design is completely fine"* - With this statement, are you referring to the thread-per-client model, with periodic polling, or the `Runnable` approach, scheduling tasks when possible, and (possibly) limiting thread-pool size?

Comment: If you writing ping/pong application, e.g. webserver where response will be followed right after request, one thread with SO_TIMEOUT will work fine. Or don't even need timeout at all. Read request until it finishes (request length could be specified in first few bytes for example), send response back. If you need to send data in both direction at the same time or push notification from server - go ahead with 2 threads per client.

Answer (score 1):

I've designed and implemented several production level realtime systems (talking about millisecond level delay or less but a handful of clients). IMHO you should definitely take NIO approach.

The core of NIO is basically select() which allow you to tackle inputs from different sockets/clients simultaneously. After that, put the events into proper queues and/or broadcast throughout the system. Then how to process the queues and allocate threads is totally independent of the IO task and is up to your own tuning.

Also take a look at ZeroMQ which essentially applies the same idea; look at their Poller over multiple Socket model. I believe most of the modern messaging framework, including JMS/EMS, TibcoRV, 29 West LBM etc (now under Informatica) are all taking similar approach.

Comment: For a small system with 4 threads, for instance, this would have a thread listening, through `select`, for incoming connections and client input, and then three worker threads to dispatch requests and broadcast to all clients, is that right? When broadcasting, if a client has a particularly slow connection, won't that affect all subsequent clients in a negative way, depending on the order in which the clients are iterated?

Comment: It won't cause selector will fire SelectionKey.OP_READ even, when socket is ready for reading.